# How do I fight The Man?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

The Man is keeping me down! Literally. This is a very hard fight, and my usual plan of "hit it til it stops moving" isn't really working out, as it seems The Man is pretty impervious to physical damage.

As a Turtle Tamer, I'm pretty much all about hitting stuff, so I am not really sure how to get through this fight, as I've gotten my butt handed to me a few times now.

How do I fight The Man and win?

Comment: What is the message you get when you try to hit the man with a physical attack? He should not be immune to physical damage

Comment: He's not immune to it, but I only do like 10 damage. My goatskin umbrella was doing much more before, but he has a physical resistance, I think.

Comment: That means he has a much higher defense than the monsters you are used to fighting. I'll expand into a full answer later, but you'll need to get more muscular and/or use your special TT class skills (shieldbutt, headbutt, etc) to take him down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The big problem you're facing here is that [The Man](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/The_Man) and his hippy counterpart, <s>The Dude</s> [The Big Wisniewski](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/The_Big_Wisniewski), are a significant step up from your usual mosters. The Frat Boys you've faced until now have an average Monster Level(ML) of 180, while The Man has a ML of 250, so basically it's not that he has some kind of physical resistance, you just *aren't powerful enough* to deal significant damage. As a Turtle Tamer you should have access to Shieldbutt, that, while being an automatic hit, still costs 10 MP per hit and probably won't be able to carry you through the whole fight. Not knowing your level or the equipment you have, I can give you some suggestions to help you in your task:

- **DELEVEL:** reducing Monster Level makes your life easier. Take a look at [this page](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Deleveling) to get an idea about what you could use. If you're not in a Hardcore ascension and have some spare meat you can get some [Slime Stacks](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Slime_stack) from the mall: in addition to dealing a good amount of damage (percentage based, so use them at the beginning for maximum effect), each stack delevels your enemy by 10%. Using 2 or 3 should reduce the ML enough to make the fight manageable;
- **ARMOR UP:** even if you reduce the ML of The Man, he still hits like a truck and has lots of HP (about 2000). Do everything you can to stay alive, while also dealing a lot of damage. Get the best equipment (without getting broke in the meanwhile), but also...
- **BUFF UP**(non Hardcore only): many clans in KoL offer free buffbots services, generally usable once per day. [Here](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Buffbot) is a list. Abuse them, they're free of charge (many accept donations in meat to replenish their MP). One advice: don't take every single buff available, look for their effect on the wiki beforehand. Some buffs are going to be detrimental for your fight, especially those that increase Monster Level.
- **KNOW YOUR ENEMY:** knowing is half the battle! The Man is Sleazy aligned, which means that [Cold](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Cold#Damage) and [Spooky](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Spooky#Damage) damage sources are going to deal double damage to him. Equip and buff yourself accordingly, on the linked pages you can find good sources of elemental damage.

And in case everything else fails...

- **RUN!** (only to return stronger than before): the Mysterious Island Quest is the penultimate step before facing the Ultimate Evil of the Kingdom, so it's supposed to be hard to test your skills. If you're having a hard time facing the man, it's going to be even harder facing the Naughty Sorceress. Spending some time leveling up is not a shame and can also turn quite profitable if you do that in a good [farming spot](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Basic_Farming). Just don't lose yourself in the vast immensity of the Kingdom!